# Vertical Alignment of text in a table in Latex (Overleaf)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, overleaf

I have the following sample code in overleaf to generate a table.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{stackengine}
    \newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[0.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}
    
\title{table}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle


\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|P{0.75cm}|P{1.25cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{0.75cm}|}
    \hline\xrowht[()]{15pt}
         \multirow{2}{*}{Test} & \multirow{2}{*}{Name} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Domain} & \multirow{2}{*}{Cell} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{MLR} & \multirow{2}{*}{$C_1$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$C_2$}\\
         \cline{3-5}\cline{7-10}\xrowht[()]{15pt}
         No & & x & y & z & Size & $\dot{m_t}$ & $\dot{m}_{in}$ & $\dot{m}_{out}$ & $\dot{m}_{avg}$ & & \\
         \hline\xrowht[()]{15pt}
         1 & Mass1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \hline\xrowht[()]{15pt}
         2 & Mass2 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0.1}  & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \hline
         \end{tabular}
         \vspace{0.5cm}
    \caption{Tests}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

This gives me,

[image]

**Problem:** I cannot get the vertical alignement of the texts inside the table to center or any other position for that matter. For example, the texts "Test No", "Name", "Cell Size", "C1" and "C2", are supposed to be vertically center aligned. Further I see that using `\hline\xrowht[()]{15pt}` gives me different box width ,**see "Domain" and "MLR" boxes**. Can anybody please help me setup this table in a proper way?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the `cellspace` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2\tabcolsep}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize
    \centering
        \caption{Tests} \label{tab:test}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{12}{0c|}}
    \hline
         \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{Test \\No.}} 
             & \multirow{4}{*}{Name} 
                 & \multicolumn{3}{0c|}{Domain} 
                     & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{Cell\\ Size}} 
                         & \multicolumn{4}{0c|}{MLR} 
                             & \multirow{4}{*}{$C_1$} 
                                 & \multirow{4}{*}{$C_2$}\\
         \cline{3-5}\cline{7-10}
          & & x & y & z & & $\dot{m_t}$ & $\dot{m}_{in}$ & $\dot{m}_{out}$ & $\dot{m}_{avg}$ & & \\
         \hline
         1 & Mass1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \hline
         2 & Mass2 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{0c|}{0.1}  & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \hline
         \end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Here is another quite different example that takes up significantly less space and relise on just a few well placed horizontal lines instead of horizontal and vertical lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
        \caption{Tests} \label{tab:test}
    \begin{tabular}{*{12}{c}}
    \toprule
         Test No. 
             & Name 
                 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Domain} 
                     & Cell Size 
                         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{MLR} 
                             & $C_1$ 
                                 & $C_2$\\
         \cmidrule{3-5}\cmidrule{7-10}
          & & x & y & z & & $\dot{m_t}$ & $\dot{m}_{in}$ & $\dot{m}_{out}$ & $\dot{m}_{avg}$ & & \\
         \midrule
         1 & Mass1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         2 & Mass2 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.1}  & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \bottomrule
         \end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Uday the second solution is ideal -- go for it

Comment: Thank you, the second table looks perfect @leandriis

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. Note the traditional position of table captions, for obvious reasons, is *above* tables.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[0.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\title{table}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|P{0.75cm}|P{1.25cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{0.75cm}|}
    \hline\xrowht[()]{15pt}
         \multirowcell{2}{Test\\No} & \multirow{4}{*}{Name} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Domain} & \multirowcell{4}{Cell\\ Size} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{MLR} & \multirowcell{4}{$C_1$} & \multirowcell{4}{$C_2$}\\
         \cline{3-5}\cline{7-10}\xrowht[()]{15pt}
         & & x & y & z & & $\dot{m_t}$ & $\dot{m}_{in}$ & $\dot{m}_{out}$ & $\dot{m}_{avg}$ & & \\
         \hline\xrowht[()]{15pt}
         1 & Mass1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \hline\xrowht[()]{15pt}
         2 & Mass2 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0.1} & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \hline
         \end{tabular}
         \vspace{0.5cm}
    \caption{Tests}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Bernard and @leandriis.

I also found another solution in stackoverflow by @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz, and I wanted to share it here.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{caption}
    
\title{table}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle



\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|P{0.75cm}|P{1.25cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{0.75cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{0.75cm}|}
    \hline
         \multirow{2}{0.75cm}{\centering Test\\ No} & \multirow{2}{*}{Name} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Domain} & \multirow{2}{0.75cm}{\centering Cell\\ Size} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{MLR} & \multirow{2}{*}{$C_1$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$C_2$}\\
         \cline{3-5}\cline{7-10}
          & & x & y & z & & $\dot{m_t}$ & $\dot{m}_{in}$ & $\dot{m}_{out}$ & $\dot{m}_{avg}$ & & \\
         \hline
         1 & Mass1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \hline
         2 & Mass2 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0.1}  & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
         \hline
         \end{tabular}
%         \vspace{0.5cm}
    \caption{Tests}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]